# Как вывести название текущей категории Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В файле `category.php` нужно вывести название текущей категории (без использования ID так как, файл `category.php` общий шаблон) заголовком. Какую функцию можно использовать?

Comment: Почему вы не смотрите стандартные темы, которые идут в wp? Там ведь все это есть.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать функцию `single_cat_title()`

```
<?php

echo single_cat_title( 'Префикс: ', 0);

?>
```

> Выводит на экран заголовок рубрики или метки. Используется за
>   пределами цикла.
>
> Если использовать эту функцию на страницах меток, то вместо заголовка
>   категории будет выведен заголовок текущей метки.
>
> **$prefix (строка)** Текст, который будет находится перед заголовком. По
>   умолчанию: ''
>
> **$display (логический)** Выводить на экран (1) или возвращать для
>   обработки (0). По умолчанию: 1 (true)